# Error LNK1223 on ARM builds

Tags: c++, windows-mobile, linker-errors, evc

eMbedded Visual C++ 3 project, that is building for PocketPC 2000. On the ARM build, the linker throws the following error:

> fatal error LNK1223: invalid or corrupt file: file contains invalid pdata contributions

On SH3, the project compiles, links, and works. The project also works when built for ARM on Visual C++ 2005, but I need to test builds specifically from eVC3.

Any ideas, please? What's a pdata contribution and how do I affect (or disable) those? It's something to do with exception handling; I've tried disabling SEH by specifying `/EHsc`, to no effect.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried EVC++ 4 to see if it builds? Is there something EVC3 gives you for your legacy build that EVC4 would not?

Comment: eVC4 does not start for me, claiming I don't have any CE SDKs installed. In fact, I have plenty, both PlatMan-compliant and CoreCon-compliant, all the way from PPC2000 to WM6.1. Rather than fight with eVC4, I went with eVC3.

Comment: Disabling SEH solved my problem, ignore my last comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very weird. I tried commenting out everything in the file. The error went away when I commented out a function that was extern "C" void __declspec(naked) with no body (body #ifdef'fed away). I have similar functions in the project, but they did not throw any errors like this. Maybe a compiler bug...

Comment: I have the same issue and can't find any working solution on internet for my case. I tried removing functions with no body as you and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t6d69w.aspx) site says but no progress. Have you any other suggestion for this case?

Comment: That was 7 years ago. Do you honestly think I remember the details?

Comment: As I said above, I found the solution, but there is almost nothing about this problem in the internet, so asking from you was my last chance. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No idea from me, but the Google-mind dredged up this thread which might give you a clue how to fix/workaround the problem... maybe:

- http://www.pocketpcjunkies.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/wince-pb/7477/Link-error-during-DEBUG-build

> After looking at the error more closely, I finally figured out that this is
>   a side-effect of my hijacking of `SC_SetDaylightTime()` in the kernel with my
>   own version.  Apparently, something that I'm doing in my code there is
>   causing the compiler to generate pdata entries that are wrong in some way.
>   A strategically-placed `#ifndef` worked around it.